# Copy from local drive to mapped sharepoint drive using Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, sharepoint

I have mapped our Sharepoint directory to a local drive on my desktop.

How can I use Python to copy a file from another local drive on the same machine to this mapped drive?

A simple code with all the necessary imports defined would be much appreciated. I am very new to Python.

Thanks.

I tried with

```
import os
import os.path
import shutil
import sys
import win32wnet
from shutil import copyfile

src = 'C:\mydirectorypath\art.txt'

dst = 'Z:\somefile.txt'

copyfile(src,dst)
```

This gives me the error:

> raise SpecialFileError("`%s` is a named pipe" % fn) with open(src,
>   'rb') as fsrc: with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst: copyfileobj(fsrc, fdst)
>
> IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('rb') or filename:
>   'C:\mydirectorypath\x07rt.txt'

Answer (score 0):

Solved it even without having to map the Sharepoint path mapping to a local drive.

used DavWWWRoot in the sharepoint path

Also the earlier error was due to the backslash (). you need to use frontslash (/)